# Elasticsearch: Index template not found

Tags: elasticsearch

My code is:

```java
PutIndexTemplateRequest ngramTemplate = new PutIndexTemplateRequest("ngram-template")
            .patterns(Arrays.asList("resourcetable-*", "termconcept-*"))
            .settings(Settings.builder().put("index.max_ngram_diff", 50));

RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchHighLevelRestClient = ElasticsearchRestClientFactory.createElasticsearchHighLevelRestClient(qualifiedHost, port, theUsername, thePassword);
AcknowledgedResponse acknowledgedResponse = elasticsearchHighLevelRestClient.indices().putTemplate(ngramTemplate, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
assert acknowledgedResponse.isAcknowledged();
```

This code is perfermod without problems.

However, when I'm trying to list all my index templates, my index template doesn't appear.

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:9200/_index_template`
{
  "index_templates": [
    {
      "name": "metrics",
      "index_template": {
        "index_patterns": [
          "metrics-*-*"
        ],
        "composed_of": [
          "metrics-mappings",
          "metrics-settings"
        ],
        "priority": 100,
        "version": 0,
        "_meta": {
          "managed": true,
          "description": "default metrics template installed by x-pack"
        },
        "data_stream": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "logs",
      "index_template": {
        "index_patterns": [
          "logs-*-*"
        ],
        "composed_of": [
          "logs-mappings",
          "logs-settings"
        ],
        "priority": 100,
        "version": 0,
        "_meta": {
          "managed": true,
          "description": "default logs template installed by x-pack"
        },
        "data_stream": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem using the Rest High Level Client for Elasticsearch version 7.10.2.

When I logged the URL of the request, I could see that `PutIndexTemplateRequest` uses the API `_template` instead of `_index_template` which apparently gets ignored when the index is created later via `CreateIndexRequest`.

The solution was to use [PutComposableIndexTemplateRequest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.10/java-rest-high-put-index-template-v2.html):

```java
PutComposableIndexTemplateRequest request = 
    new PutComposableIndexTemplateRequest().name(INDEX_TEMPLATE_NAME);

Settings settings = Settings.builder()
    .loadFromSource(MY_SETTINGS_JSON_STRING, XContentType.JSON).build();
Template template = new Template(settings, null, null);

ComposableIndexTemplate composableIndexTemplate =
            new ComposableIndexTemplate(List.of("my-index-pattern"),
                template, null, null, null, null);

request.indexTemplate(composableIndexTemplate);

try {
    client.indices().putIndexTemplate(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
        // handle error
}
```